# What is the best way to persist the time a service has been restarted in MYSQL database

Tags: java, hibernate, session, jpa, dropwizard

I am trying to save the time my java service is restarted on a debian server into a MYSQL server. The java application is a dropwizard project. I tried doing it from Java, but it requires an Object creation , the data access object, a hibernate config file and mapping file. Which seems like an overdo, is there an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you can use raw JDBC?

Comment: thanks Stefaan, that seems resonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate is just an option you can use to access the database, but it is not the only way.  If you don't want to use Hibernate you can just use a direct connection using JDBC

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html

That should get you going with how to setup a connection and how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you want to use Java, you don't need to use hibernate. All you need is something akin to the following:

public class ServiceRestartServlet extends HttpServlet {

```
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
  Connection conn = null;
  try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(System.getProperty("jdbc.url"), System.getProperty("jdbc.user"), System.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
    conn.setAutocommit(false);
    PreparedStatement insertStatement = conn.prepareStatement("insert into serviceRestartLog (serviceName, restartTime) values (?, now())");
    insertStatement.setString(1, req.getParameter("serviceName"));
    insertStatement.execute();
    conn.commit();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    System.err.println(new java.util.Date()+" Save failed -- "+e.getMessage());
  } finally {
    try {
      conn.close();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
      System.err.println(new java.util.Date()+" connection failed to close -- "+e.getMessage() );
    }
  }
  public void init(ServletContext ctx) {
     Class.forName(System.getProperty("jdbc.drivers")).newInstance();
  }
}
```

Just activate this servlet in your web.xml and issue a request with the application name after creating the table and you should be golden.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'mysql' command line

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD -e 'update WHATEVER set DATE_RESTARTED=NOW();'
```

Search help if you don't want to pass password on a command line.

Comment: would this be in my java program? How is this different from raw JDBC?